# Price elasticity: The comnment in the solution is not correct?

Tags: r, python, elasticity

The comment in the solution says :

*We display all elasticities of purchase probability on the same plot.
We observe that the **Career-focused** segment are the least elastic when compared to the rest.
So, their purchase probability elasticity is not as affected by price.*

My plots are just like in the solution, I have also plotted a plot which the elasticity is from 0 to -2 to get a better exposure. Based on the plots the least least elastic segment should be **Well-off** and not **Career-focused** since the slope is more linear. Have I misunderstood the solution or is it wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably mean least steep rather than linear.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov sorry, yes you are correct